# Not sure why my Vue app build.js file appears to be my index.html file after build in Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, webpack

After I deploy my Vue app to [Firebase](https://vue-game-day-front-end.firebaseapp.com/), it appears as if my build.js file is the same as my index.html file.  When I go the site, I get nothing.  Looking the the console, I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` at line 1 of build.js.
If I then reload it with the Network tab open, I see build.js listed as a resource, but when I click on it, it shows the same contents as index.html.  (The build.js file is in fact js after I build it on my end).

This is my first time using Firebase, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong in the firebase.json (which I just copied from a tutorial):

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "./dist",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }]
    }
}
```

I'm not using any other firebase tools.

[image: File Structure]

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Does your app's directory include a root `config` folder with an `index.js` file?

Comment: no config folder.  I'm using webpack, so I have a `webpack.config.js`

Comment: can u show a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: added the folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you firebase.json should look like this:

```
hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Run `firebase deploy --only hosting` and it should be good. Source [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config)

Make sure your output for that command looks something like this:

```
=== Deploying to 'your-project-name'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[zero-to-prod-test]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[zero-to-prod-test]: found 16 files in public/build <---- THIS TELLS YOU IF THE FILES ARE BEING COPIED
✔  hosting[zero-to-prod-test]: file upload complete
i  hosting[zero-to-prod-test]: finalizing version...
✔  hosting[zero-to-prod-test]: version finalized
i  hosting[zero-to-prod-test]: releasing new version...
✔  hosting[zero-to-prod-test]: release complete
```

That way to can debbug is something is wrong on the data transfer.

On your case your index.html is pointing to `dist/build.js` intead of `/build.js` that is causing the problem, so it doesnt look like a firebase problem but a webpack problem. Check your assets generation process.

Comment: No change.  Thanks though.

Comment: are u 100% sure that your build is working fine? according to the docs (and experience) the problem if your relative path, take a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config

Comment: It says it completes fine.  When I look at dist/build.js, it's full of minified javascript, so I'm assuming it OK.
`Version: webpack 3.12.0
Time: 10390ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    build.js   808 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
build.js.map  4.87 MB       0  [emitted]         main`

Comment: I'm not sure... take a look at this https://vue-game-day-front-end.firebaseapp.com/dist/build.js ... it's empty

Comment: If you view the source, it's index.html.

Comment: what i mean if that your build.js is empty, that's why you application doesnt work

Comment: But what I'm saying is that on my local side, it's not empty.  It's not getting moved up correctly or something.

Comment: whats ur output on `firebase deploy --only hosting`?

Comment: basically there are 3 files, and they are deployed.  releasing new version... release complete.

Comment: ok, i found the problem, it's where your webpack configuration is pointing to the js, notice this https://vue-game-day-front-end.firebaseapp.com/build.js ... it exists... but onr cause you are pointing to https://vue-game-day-front-end.firebaseapp.com/dist/build.js .. it does not exists... fix your index.html / webpack configuration to point to /build.js instead

Comment: You bet.  I'm still learning webpack.  I'm trying to find the balance between webpack-dev and webpack.  In my index, if I change the script src to `build.js` it doesn't work locally, but does remotely.  It would be nice if I could figure out how to make it work both places without needing to change anything between deployments and without cluttering my `root` with `build.js` and `build.js.map`.

Comment: make it simple... an if statement with an env variable for NODE_ENV check your environment should do the trick... if `production` one of not the other..., this is very opinionated tho